# webservice to accept and return an xml document

Tags: xml, web-services, asmx

I need to design a web service which accepts xml and returns an xml.
What I get from the input xml is set of data which I need to insert into a DB and send the confirmation of the inserted rows with certain IDs which should be again sent as an xml.

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: :( its a client requirement to develop using a webservice

Comment: Does the client require that you use an ASMX web service, or can you use a WCF web service? You should make the client aware that I am telling you that ASMX should not be used for new development. Tell the client that **John Saunders** said so.

Comment: Seriously, the client may simply be making the same mistake many developers still make: they think that ASMX is the proper way to create web services in .NET, so they specify to use ASMX. They are simply mistaken, and we, as their developers, need to point out their mistake to them.

Comment: Ask them if they have a specific reason for wanting to use this ancient technology. Chances are that any requirements they had for using ASMX can be met with WCF (unless they require that you use .NET 2.0 or something like that).

Comment: Ok John Will suggest them the same